# !DOCTYPE declaration messing with my font sizes

Tags: html, css, fonts, size, doctype

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
```

The above is the doctype suggested by the W3 validator for my site.

I've been really stupid and developed quite abit without declaring the doctype at the top of each page.

Luckily it only seems to have affected the font sizes/weights, which are all now massive for some reason.

Below is an example of css from my site. Any suggestions?

```css
table.bookings {
    width: 744;
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#484848;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: What browser is this in?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox, latest versions.

Comment: try to use the  doc type for html5 same  <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Is that all you need for html5? Just <!DOCTYPE html> ?

Comment: Yes, please check [this](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/) link too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz correct your Doctype, i think your using html4.01 so its:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

For new HTML5, the doctype will be:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Also correct your font-family, its not wrong but as far as w3v rules you have to mention the font is a sans-serif, cursive etc...

```
font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
```

Comment: Wow, that works great! The fonts still appear larger with that particular doctype, but the san-serif fixes it! Thanks!

Comment: The doctype is obviously the same as in the question (where it was written in a misleading way). Adding `sans-serif` is not a must, it does not mention anything, and it simply says (in this case) that if `Helvetica` is not available, then the browser’s default font should be used. (And in fact, Windows recognizes Helvetica as a synonym for Arial when genuine Arial is not available.) So if this seems to have solved a problem, it was rather different from the one in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The validator does not suggest any doctype. It simply *defaults* to a particular doctype.

By adding a doctype from a certain set of alternatives, you trigger “standards mode” in browsers. This really means just “not intentionally broken mode”, i.e. it means avoiding “quirks mode”, which is a collective name for browser modes where they more or less imitate bugs of old browsers (something like IE 5 bugs). You are apparently using such a doctype, even though the question lacks the `<` and `>` characters that are part of the doctype string.

[Quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) vs. standards mode affects a large number of things, especially in CSS. This may include, among other things, breaking inheritance of font sizes. That is, font size declared for an element containing a table might not get inherited by the cells of the table. From the excerpt posted, it is impossible to say what really happens. But in standards mode, at least the part `width: 744` is ignored as syntactically wrong.

If you have written a page that now uses quirks mode, as you apparently have, then the reasonable options are to keep it that way and to rewrite it. For new pages, use standards mode from the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

once you declare that this is an html doc type , you can not put inside it an css code , the browser will mess interpret it , so put the css code away in a separate file .

Comment: Actually you can. You simply need to enclose the css code in a <style></style> tag. See https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_style.asp

Comment: @quant  i meant to say you declared its html document , and you put css in which is contradiction , css  is one thing and html is another thing , these two different in doc types .